# Custom distance function between every row of two dataframes

Tags: pandas

I have two dataframes, I want to calculate the "distance" between every row in one data frame compared to every row in another using a custom distance measure (for example euclidian for the first column, taxi cab for the second, etc). Is there a way to do this quickly using broadcasting?

Answer (score 0):

you can simply create a custom function and use that in apply function:

for example:

```
def custom_func(a, b):
    result = a + b for example: 
    return result

df = df.apply(custom_func)
```

if you want answer that needs to be tested in some dataset, please add the data. But Idea is you can create any custom functions and passed in your pandas apply function.
more about apply function and examples are: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html

Also you may want to check `applymap` function in pandas too. https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html